# How can I make all my buttons "touch up insides"?

Tags: objective-c

I created an app where users can touch buttons on a scroll view to go to another view, but when you scroll, it gets stuck on the buttons, and can only scroll when not touching the buttons.

So I suppose touch up inside would fix this but how would I make all my modal connections into touch up insides?

Comment: Have you seen `exclusiveTouch` yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the storyboards, then they should be on touch up inside by default.

My guess is that your scrollview has `Delays Content Touches` disabled, you can set them via interface builder or `self.scrollView.delaysContentTouches = YES;`

Comment: This is very likely. If delaysContentTouches is NO, then pinch-zooms will also be broken.